# How to detect key press and release?

Tags: macos, swiftui, keyboard, keypress

Not much to say other than the title. I want to be able to take action in a SwiftUI view when a key is pressed and when it is released (on macOS). Is there any good way to do this in SwiftUI, and if not, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately keyboard event handling is one of those areas where it's painfully obvious that SwiftUI was designed first and foremost for iOS, with macOS being an afterthought.

If the key you're trying to detect is a modifier to a mouse click, such as `cmd`, `option`, or `shift`, you can use the `.modifiers` with `onTapGesture` to distinguish it from an unmodified `onTapGesture`.  In that case, my experience with it is that you want the `.onTapGesture` call that uses `.modifiers` to *precede* the unmodified one.

Handling general key events for arbitrary views requires going outside of SwiftUI.

If you just need it for one View, one possibility is to implement that view with `AppKit` so you can receive the keyboard events via the ordinary Cocoa `firstResponder` mechanism, and then wrap that view in SwiftUI's `NSViewRepresentable`.  In that case your wrapped `NSView` would update some `@State` property in `NSViewRespresentable`.  A lot of developers using SwiftUI for macOS do it this way. While this is fine for a small number of views, if it turns out that you have to implement a lot of views in AppKit to make them usable in SwiftUI, then you're kind of defeating the point of using SwiftUI anyway.  In that case, just make it an ordinary Cocoa app.

But there is another way...

You could use another thread that uses `CGEventSource` to poll the keyboard state actively in conjunction with a SwiftUI `@EnvironmentObject` or `@StateObject` to communicate keyboard state changes to the SwiftUI `View`s that are interested in them.

Let's say you want to detect when the up-arrow is pressed.  To detect the key, I use an extension on `CGKeyCode`.

```swift
import CoreGraphics

extension CGKeyCode
{
    // Define whatever key codes you want to detect here
    static let kVK_UpArrow: CGKeyCode = 0x7E

    var isPressed: Bool {
        CGEventSource.keyState(.combinedSessionState, key: self)
    }
}
```

Of course, you have to use the right key codes.  I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/chipjarred/cbb324c797aec865918a8045c4b51d14) containing all of the old key codes.  Rename them to be more Swifty if you like.  The names listed go back to classic MacOS and were defined in *Inside Macintosh*.

With that extension defined, you can test if a key is pressed anytime you like:

```swift
if CGKeyCode.kVK_UpArrow.isPressed { 
    // Do something in response to the key press.
}
```

Note these are *not* key-up or key-down events.  It's simply a boolean detecting if the key is pressed when you perform the check.  To behave more like events, you'll need to do that part yourself by keeping track of key state changes.

There are multiple ways of doing this, and the following code is not meant to imply that this is the "best" way.  It is simply *a* way.  In any case, something like the following code would go (or be called from) wherever you do global initialization when you app starts.

```swift
// These will handle sending the "event" and will be fleshed 
// out further down
func dispatchKeyDown(_ key: CGKeyCode) {...}
func dispatchKeyUp(_ key: CGKeyCode) {...}

fileprivate var keyStates: [CGKeyCode: Bool] =
[
    .kVK_UpArrow: false,
    // populate with other key codes you're interested in
]

fileprivate let sleepSem = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
fileprivate let someConcurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "polling", attributes: .concurrent)

someConcurrentQueue.async 
{
    while true
    {
        for (code, wasPressed) in keyStates
        {
            if code.isPressed 
            {
                if !wasPressed 
                {
                    dispatchKeyDown(code)
                    keyStates[code] = true
                }
            }
            else if wasPressed 
            {
                dispatchKeyUp(code)
                keyStates[code] = false
            }
        }
        
        // Sleep long enough to avoid wasting CPU cycles, but 
        // not so long that you miss key presses.  You may 
        // need to experiment with the .milliseconds value.
        let_ = sleepSem.wait(timeout: .now() + .milliseconds(50))
    }
}
```

The idea is just to have some code that periodically polls key states, compares them with previous states, dispatches an appropriate "event" when they change, and updates the previous states.   The code above does that by running an infinite loop in a concurrent task. It requires creating a `DispatchQueue` with the `.concurrent` attribute.  You can't use it on `DispatchQueue.main` because that queue is *serial* not concurrent, so the infinite loop would block the main thread, and the program would become unresponsive.  If you already have a concurrent `DispatchQueue` you use for other reasons, you can just use that one instead of creating one just for polling.

However, any code that accomplishes the basic goal of periodic polling will do, so if you don't already have a concurrent `DispatchQueue` and would prefer not to create one just to poll for keyboard states, which would be a reasonable objection, here's an alternate version that uses `DispatchQueue.main` with a technique called "async chaining" to avoid blocking/sleeping:

```swift
fileprivate var keyStates: [CGKeyCode: Bool] =
[
    .kVK_UpArrow: false,
    // populate with other key codes you're interested in
]

fileprivate func pollKeyStates()
{
    for (code, wasPressed) in keyStates
    {
        if code.isPressed 
        {
            if !wasPressed 
            {
                dispatchKeyDown(code)
                keyStates[code] = true
            }
        }
        else if wasPressed 
        {
            dispatchKeyUp(code)
            keyStates[code] = false
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(50))
    {
        // The infinite loop from previous code is replaced by
        // infinite chaining.
        pollKeyStates()
    }
}

// Start up key state polling
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(50)) {
    pollKeyStates()
}
```

With code in place to detect when keys are pressed, you now need a way to communicate that to your SwiftUI `View`s.  Again, there's more than one way to skin that cat.  Here's an overly simplistic one that will update a `View` whenever the up-arrow is pressed, but you'll probably want to implement something a bit more sophisticated... probably something that allows views to specify what keys they're interested in responding to.

```swift
class UpArrowDetector: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var isPressed: Bool = false
}

let upArrowDetector = UpArrowDetector()

func dispatchKeyDown(_ key: CGKeyCode) 
{
    if key == .kVK_UpArrow {
        upArrowDetector.isPressed = true
    }
}

func dispatchKeyUp(_ key: CGKeyCode) {
    if key == .kVK_UpArrow {
        upArrowDetector.isPressed = false
    }
}

// Now we hook it into SwiftUI
struct UpArrowDetectorView: View
{
    @StateObject var detector: UpArrowDetector

    var body: some View
    {
        Text(
            detector.isPressed 
                ? "Up-Arrow is pressed" 
                : "Up-Arrow is NOT pressed"
        )
    }
}

// Use the .environmentObject() method of `View` to inject the
// `upArrowDetector`
struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        UpArrowDetectorView()
            .environmentObject(upArrowDetector)
    }
}
```

I've put a full, compilable, and working example at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/chipjarred/e39c48619e591fbf9588af3d3684bed9) patterned on code you linked to in comments.  It's slightly refactored from the above code, but all the parts are there, including starting up the polling code.

I hope this points you in a useful direction.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful! Thank you so much for the detailed response! I really hope apple takes more interest in macOS and adds a way to do this in swiftUI, but this is a great solution for now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm working on implementing this now and I have one question. I've never worked with concurrency before and I wasn't sure what I'm supposed to do on the line `someConcurrentQueue.async {`. Can `someConcurrentQueue` just be whatever I want, like `keyboardManagerQueue`? Sorry if this is a dumb question. Thanks!

Comment: `someConcurrentQueue` is just a stand-in for a `DispatchQueue` that was created with the `.concurrent` attribute (`let someConcurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queueNameGoesHere", attributes: .concurrent)`).  You could use an existing queue as long as it's not a serial queue, which means you can't use `DispatchQueue.main` with my code example.

Comment: BTW - there are ways you could use `DispatchQueue.main`.  Instead of an finite loop in the `async` closure, you could use "async chaining".   To do that put the code from the closure into a named function, and then use `DispatchQueue.main.async` in the function to call it self instead of an infinite loop.  In that case, you don't want to sleep, because that would block the main thread.  As I said, there are multiple ways to do it.

Comment: @CameronDelong, I updated my answer both to include the creation of the concurrent queue, and with an alternate implementation that can be used with `DispatchQueue.main`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! I'm also having trouble figuring out where to put some of the code. When you say "where I do global initiation", I don't think I have globals? So I'm not sure where that would be. It that just somewhere at the top level? And does most of the code after that go in the same place?

Comment: Also one more question I have is, while I was having trouble figuring out this method, I tried to implement the way with `NSViewRepresentable`, but I had the problem that I have a `NagivationView`, and the destination of that navigationView is where I need the keyboard input. So keyboard input would either not work when the NavigationView was focused, or cause the NavigationView to lose focus instantly after selecting an item on it, leading to it just flashing blue before turning to a darker gray. Do you know if this approach with `CGEventSource` would have the same problem?

Comment: Regarding where your initialization code should go... Wherever your ContentView is created.  That used to be in `AppDelegate.didFinishLaunching()` but a lot of projects use `WindowGroup`.  If you don't have an obvious place to put it, you could put it in a `static` function and use `static` properties instead of globals for `keyStates` and `upArrowDetector` (or you version of it).  Make make sure the code that polls for the key states is started before `ContentView.body` is called.  You will still need to inject the `upArrowDetector` (or your equivalent) as instance properties though.

Comment: As for the other question, the reason you had problems with the `NSViewRepresentable` solution has to do with the way `NavigationView` steals/sets the `firstResponder` behind the scenes.  The good and bad thing about using `CGEventSource` to detect keys is that it's global... meaning it doesn't care about `firstResponder`, but that means if you use it in multiple Views, you will need to add some code to manage how the "events" are dispatched that makes sense for your app.

Comment: BTW - I mentioned there are other ways to deal handle it keyboard events.  I have a SwiftPackage called `MacMenuBar` that handles the menu bar in a SwiftUI way (another pain point for SwiftUI on macOS), and I provide a Sudoku app to demonstrate how to use it.  I wanted the Sudoku puzzle to respond to key events so I took another approach that intercepts events from the AppKit event loop before SwiftUI gets its grubby paws on them.

Comment: https://github.com/chipjarred/MacMenuBar  .  `NSGameWindow.swift`, `NSGameHostingView.swift` in `Cocoa-BasedTypes` folder, and in `Views/KeyboardHacks` there is `KeyResponder.swift` and `KeyResponderGroup.swift`.    It's all very special case for that particular app, but it may give you ideas.  The purpose was to demonstrate `MacMenuBar`.  Keyboard handling was just an incidental thing.  I'm not sure I'd do it that way again.

Comment: I tried to take the approach of using static vars, and I can't quite get it to work. I've created a file called KeyboardManager, with a class KeyboardManager to store the static values, and in my case a SpaceDetector class for now (as well as the CGKeyCode extension): https://pastebin.com/WCgHwyRJ. I then added the StateObject to the View I needed the input in, and the text to test. Xcode throws an error when I call that view, `Missing argument for parameter 'detector' in call`. I tried passing `KeyboardManager.spaceDetector`, which got rid of the error.

Comment: It still didn't work which I assume was because I was never starting the loop to get the key states? But I'm not sure where to run that code. I tried `KeyboardManager.pollKeyStates()` in `Window Group`, but `WindowGroup` throws `Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'`.

Comment: Where is your main view created? ie, `ContentView` unless you changed it.  I don't mean where it is defined.  I mean there is some place where an instance of it is created.   Do you have it in a repo on Github I can take a look?

Comment: OK, so I just looked over the code from your pastebin link.  I think the easiest way would be to put a `static var isInitialized = false` in your `KeyboardManager`.  Rename your `spaceDetector` property and make it private.  Add a `public` computed property that calls `pollKeyStates()` if `isInitialized` is `false`, sets it to `true` and returns the private spaceDetector

Comment: Also if you want to start it up in Window Group, you probably have to explicitly `return` the view.  Adding non-`View` code messes up `View`'s result builder.   You can run into similar issues putting non-`View` code in `View.body`.

Comment: I'll work on adding that when I have a chance. However I'm still having trouble running the code in WindowGroup. I just tried using print() and returning ContentView but I still get an error, now its `Cannot use explicit 'return' statement in the body of result builder 'ViewBuilder'`. Here's code: https://pastebin.com/UGgxt1Nc. Also tysm for all the help so far, I would've been stuck ages ago without it

Comment: I made this [gist](https://gist.github.com/chipjarred/e39c48619e591fbf9588af3d3684bed9) for you.  I roughly patterned it after the code from your pastebin link so hopefully it's more obvious how to initialize it.

Comment: Just got it working, thank you so much! Sorry if I was a bit incompetent, I’m fairly new to swift so I wasn’t sure exactly what I was doing. This worked perfectly for what I needed though, and now I can finally get on to other parts of my app! Thanks!!

Comment: Awesome!  I'm glad I was able to help

Comment: I can't add an answer (closed), but I was able to get an `onKeyDown` event firing by subclassing `NSTextView` with `override func keyDown(...)` method override. For some reason, the keyDown handler doesn't fire with NSTextField but it does with NSTextView. It seems to be the least hacky solution that I've come across (e.g. doesn't require polling).

Comment: @danneu Thanks for the solution, however I covered using Cocoa (AppKit) in the fourth paragraph of my answer. The problem is the question is about capturing key presses in SwiftUI apps, not Cocoa apps, which means all such views have to be wrapped by `NSViewRepresentable` which might be objectionable when there many different `View` types that need the functionality, and though I didn’t originally mention it, it also doesn’t address if it’s needed globally, not just in certain views.

Comment: @danneu another approach is intercept `CGEvent` by subclassing (or swizzling) `NSHostingView`, but that means having to intercept/forward to/restore `firstResponder`.  That’s too much messing with Cocoa innards to be a clean solution.

Comment: @Dan I'm glad you found it useful.  Apple is improving SwiftUI support for macOS, but they still have a long way to go to achieve parity with Cocoa apps, and maybe they never will.  I kind of expect that we'll probably always have to reach down into lower levels for some behavior or other.

Comment: Thank you so much. It took forever to find an answer that didn't require some super hacky way to do things. :)

Answer (score 1):

in the meanwhile (Xcode 15, iOS 17, **macOS 14**) we have some support for detecting key press events in SwiftUI, that we can use, when developing for macOS. There is a new view modifier **.onKeyPress**, that helps in such cases.

Here is an **example code**, how to implement:

```
TextField("new name of the player", text: $newName)
   .focused($isTextFieldFocussed)
   .autocorrectionDisabled()
   .onSubmit { confirmRenaming() }   // <RETURN> key pressed
   .onKeyPress(.escape) {            // <ESCAPE> key tracking
       cancelRenaming()
       return .handled 
   }
```

The return options are **.handeled** OR **.ignored** and tells the system, that the key input is already fully handled or not, which means the system will still take care for the key input (and do whatever with it).

Try to clean and rebuild because the canvas view sometimes does not really work with the key events.

Answer (score 1):

I'm building a complex macOS(13|14) app and the 'default' .keyboardShortcut() was not triggering my button action as explained in the headers.

I wanted to display a custom view in a .sheet modifier and there I would dismiss the sheet by hitting the .esc key or hitting .return key.

.keyboardShortcut() was not working consistently and often would beep. The beep in Cocoa is indicative of system events not properly handled through the responder chain. Well yes there is still NSResponder under the hood on SwiftUI.

The following code allows you to get key downs into your view. Since this solved my issue I wanted to post it here as another simpler mechanism for handling any key down in any view. This is obviously macOS code and relatively brief.

At the heart I'm using 2 old Cocoa APIs NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents and NSEvent.removeMonitor

MyView, will now be able to distinguish between a .mouseClick or .return and call whatever logic.

```
struct Demo {
    // Convenience
    // https://gist.github.com/rdev/627a254417687a90c493528639465943
    //
    extension UInt16 {
        // Layout-independent Keys
        // eg.These key codes are always the same key on all layouts.
        static let returnKey: UInt16 = 0x24
        static let enter: UInt16 = 0x4C
        static let space: UInt16 = 0x31
    }

    struct MyView: View {
        @State var monitorID: Any?

        func handleAction(_ type: String) {
            // do your work here
        }

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    handleAction(".mouseClick")
                }) {
                    Text("Hit return")
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                self.monitorID = NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) { event in
                    if event.keyCode == .returnKey || event.keyCode == .enter {
                        handleAction(".return")
                        return nil
                    } else if event.keyCode == .space {
                        handleAction(".space")
                        return nil
                    }
                    // allow others to handle this event
                    return event
                }
            })
            .onDisappear(perform: {
                if let id = self.monitorID {
                    // clean up or else we are called with older captured values
                    NSEvent.removeMonitor(id)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```