# Detect Cmd + klick on Catalyst with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I want to trigger differed events on tap, double tap and cmd+tap in a Mac- Catalyst application.

For the first two things I used the

```
.onTapGesture(count: 2) {
   print("double tap")
}
.onTapGesture(count: 1) {
   print("tapped")
}
```

and I know that on macOS there is an option to use this function:

`.gesture(TapGesture().modifiers(.command).onEnded{ "cmd + tap" })`.

But what is the best way to do this in a Catalyst app?

Thank you for your Ideas

Comment: any update regarding this question ? @TS251

Comment: @JasonKrowl yes, I used this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68204982/how-to-detect-key-press-and-release-in-swiftui-macos . When .onTapGesture() is called, I check if the cmd key is pressed.